# How to compare the first date and the last date?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I have this table:

```
|NAME(Key)       |     LOGIN_DATE      |
|----------------|---------------------|
|mark            | 2012-10-10 10:35:00 |
|mark            | 2012-10-10 10:40:00 |
|mark            | 2012-10-10 10:45:00 |
```

I want to know how to find the difference between last and first dates:

```
|NAME            |     TIME_DIFF       |
|----------------|---------------------|
|mark            | 10 minutes          |
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Nothing is impossible buddy, use de timedate functions :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT name
     , SEC_TO_TIME( MAX(TIME_TO_SEC(login_date))
                  - MIN(TIME_TO_SEC(login_date))
                  ) x 
  FROM my_table 
 GROUP 
    BY name;
```

Answer (score 4):

```
select 
    name, 
    concat( timestampdiff( minute,
                           min( login_date ), 
                           max( login_date ) ),
            ' minutes' 
    ) as 'login duration'
from my_table
group by name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MIN(`LOGIN_DATE`), MAX(`LOGIN_DATE`) WHERE `NAME(Key)` = 'mark';
```

Comment: I'm guessing the OP wanted something a little more generic

Comment: This would only give him the oldest and most recent timestamps that the user logged in at, it doesn't do the comparison between them to show the differences.